# This version of cli is only compatible with angular version 2.3.1 or better

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting the following error message when building my angular 2 app by executing the command ng build.  "This version of cli is only compatible with angular version 2.3.1 or better. Please upgrade your angular version."

Below is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mrdb.web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: OK. What is your question? Isn't the message crystal clear?

Comment: I am new to angular. I thought angular 2.0.0 is  the latest version of angular 2. If I need to use angular 2, what is the latest version

Comment: The latest version of Angular is 1.4.3 (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I really don't see why you would force you t use an obsolete version of Angular. Angular 4 and Angular 2 are the same framework. The version has been upgraded due to a minimal breaking change, that's all.

Comment: The latest version is 4.1.3 (1.4.3 is a typo) as JB Nizet wrote.

Answer (score 1):

you have pinned your version of angular to 2.0.0

you need to upgrade your angular dependencies to the latest version.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

Comment: Hi leon, My client doesnt want me to work on angular 4. I have been told to use angular2 only

Comment: I am bit confused with the versioning

Comment: Why wouldn't they want to work with angular 4? It's the latests stable version of "angular 2"

Comment: They are already been using angular 2 for some time . They are using material design as well. Angular 4 has some path breaking changes with material design hence they want to push that to the future as they are currently working on a strict deadline

Comment: In that case I would try to upgrade to the latest version in the 2.x branch. change ^4.0.0 on all angular dependencies to 2.4.10 and try that.

Comment: I have done that but now its complaining of the version of its dependencies. How do I ascertain the ones listed in the package.json is compatible with 2.4.10 angular version

Comment: You will have to go back and read each dependencies release logs and try to figure out which version of the dep is compatible.